# A question in linear algebra about independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space over $\Bbb R$ and let$\{v_1,v_2,\ldots v_k\}$ be a linearly independent set in V. Show that if $w \notin Span(v_1 \ldots v_k)$, then the set$\{v_1+w,v_2+w \ldots v_k+w\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $a_1,\ldots, a_k\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$a_1(v_1+w)+\cdots+a_k(v_k+w)=0\iff a_1 v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k=-\sum_ia_iw$$

- What's the contradiction  that we find if $\sum_i a_i\ne0$?
- Since now we have $\sum_i a_i=0$ what we can conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_1(v_1+w)+a_2(v_2+w)+.......a_k(v_k+w) = 0$, for some numbers $a_1,..a_k$. Then,

$a_1v_1+...a_kv_k=-(a_1+...a_k)w$. If $a_1+..a_k=0$ then by linear independence of $v_i's$ we have all $a_i's$ are $0$. $a_1+..a_k \neq 0$ then $w \in span\{v_1,..v_k\}$- contradiction. So, all $a_i's =0$ and we are done.